# UIButton causes (lldb) error with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I've seen this issue many times on SO, but the solutions to those questions have not fixed my issue.

I dynamically create a UIButton and add it to my view. I add a target to the button, which is a function.

The target functions runs (i.e. the print statement runs), and then I see the (lldb) error in the console, and the exception breakpoint highlights the `class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate` line of AppDelegate.swift with the error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=x020000000c)`, and the app crashes.

I know that this is commonly caused by selector errors (i.e. the colon indicating a parameter-accepting function), but I've tried all variations of colons and no-colons, to no avail.

Any help is appreciated

Source:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.loginButton = UIButton()
        self.loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, self.view.bounds.width - 20, 40)
        self.loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        self.view.addSubview(self.loginButton)

        self.loginButton.addTarget(self, action: "initLogin:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
    }

    func initLogin(button: UIButton)
    {
        println("Logging in...")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I took the relevant code from my project and put it in a blank project, the error persisted.

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but if you put a whitespace between forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside?

Comment: @NekakKinich unfortunatley that is not the issue :) I wish, though!

Comment: I know, but XCode and Swift are very special :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

It looks like init is a special keyword Swift uses when bridging ObjC code. From the docs:

> Initialization
>
> To instantiate an Objective-C class in Swift, you call one of its
>   initializers with Swift syntax. When Objective-C init methods come
>   over to Swift, they take on native Swift initializer syntax. The
>   “init” prefix gets sliced off and becomes a keyword to indicate that
>   the method is an initialize

So if you change your code to something like below, it will work.

Thanks to @cedabob for the reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var loginButton: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

            self.loginButton = UIButton()
            self.loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, self.view.bounds.width - 20, 40)
            self.loginButton.setTitle("Login", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            self.loginButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            self.view.addSubview(self.loginButton)

            self.loginButton.addTarget(self, action: "login:", forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        }

        func login(button: UIButton)
        {
            println("Logging in...")
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }
    }
```

Comment: ... unfortunately that's correct. No idea why. Swift is infuriating sometimes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: From the swift docs: "The “init” prefix gets sliced off and becomes a keyword to indicate that the method is an initializer."

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-XID_26

Comment: Thanks for the link @chedabob - edited the original answer to include

Comment: @chedabob thanks for the reference. That's pretty counter-intuitive for a swift-only project.

Comment: Same compiler tho, I guess is why it happens.